# Create different database per account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am new to ruby on rails. I am using mongomapper and I want to create single database per account. Suppose If user will login, new database will create with the username of the login user and if already created then it will switch to that database.
I am trying with the following code in the model : 
     `class User
      include MongoMapper::Document
      include ActionView::Helpers
      connection(Mongo::Connection.new('localhost', 27017))
      set_database_name "#{current_user.username}
      key :name, String
      key :email, String,   :required => true
      key :username, String,   :required => true,   :unique => true
    end`

But I am not getting username. If I put this code "connection(Mongo::Connection.new('localhost', 27017))" in controller its giving error. Is there any way to establish new database connection from application controller. Waiting for the solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: I am getting this error "undefined method `connection' for #<LoansController:0xb4e03814>" when I use database connection code in my controller because I am not getting username in the model.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What problem are you trying to solve? Why not just have one database for all users

Comment: Actually I want to create SAAS system like basecamp.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution we can crate new database from controller:

```
MongoMapper.database = "my_db"
```

If its already created then it will switch to the "my_db" database otherwise it will create new db and switch to that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to checkout the [aparment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) gem:

> Apartment provides tools to help you deal with multiple tenants in your Rails application. If you need to have certain data sequestered based on account or company, but still allow some data to exist in a common tenant, Apartment can help.

When creating a new user, you can call:

```
Apartment::Tenant.create('tenant_name')
```

And when the user logs in, switch the db for that user:

```
Apartment::Tenant.switch!('tenant_name')
```

Even works for subdomains.

Comment: Can we use this gem with mongomapper?

Comment: Maybe, I never use Mongo.